# Why sagen is not properly used in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Let's consider the below sentence

> ich ***sag*** dir später Bescheid

Which means, I will let you know later, although the sentence looks like in ***Präsens***. Therefore i expect to see ***Ich sage*** instead of ***Ich sag***. An ***e*** is missed at the end of ***sag***

So, can anybody explain me, if **sag** is used correctly or not?

Comment: Dear Downvoters,
Please explain what is wrong with my question, so i can improve it.

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara I would argue that "sagen" *is* properly used here because "sag" is a grammatically correct variant (mainly of colloquial speech). This might explain the downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

In colloquial speech it is correct and common to omit the *-e* in the first person singular *Präsens*, even in written communication.

The tenses in German are not strictly organized temporally. The *Futur* is mostly used for announcement regarding the remote future and sounds somewhat portentous (besides it can be used to mark assumptions regarding the present, e.g. *Er wird schon weg sein.* – 'he might be gone'). For talking about the near future in everyday life, the *Präsens* is by far more common.

Answer (score 0):

German tenses are different from English tenses. German *Gegenwart* can describe things that happen now, in the present, but also in the past and you also can use it for events in the future. I wrote about it in detail in [another answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/44405/ill-call-you-ich-rufe-dich-an-why-no-werde-here/44406#44406).

And omitting trailing *e*'s in Verbs and some other parts of speech is quite common in German.